# Dell 1950: How to tell what generation it is?

Tags: dell-poweredge

The 1950 exists in Gen 1, Gen 2 and Gen 3 variants. This is important because the Gen 2 and 3 variants can take 64GB RAM while Gen 1 only 32 GB.

I have looked high and low, and cannot find out how to tell one gen from another, *except* that for Gen 3, the "original configuration" page on the Dell site is supposed to indicate that it is Gen 3.

I have a pair of these, from Nov 2006. They do not show up as Gen 3 in any way I can tell.

There are 8 RAM slots... so either they take max 4GB modules or 8GB modules. There is no way to tell, that I know of, since the Gen1 and 2 systems look and smell the same.

How do I tell if they are Gen 1 or 2?

Comment: Do you have the Express Service tag? I would guess a call to Dell support might provide you the info you want.

Comment: You can even look up the service tag at Dell's web site.

Comment: If you know it's not Gen 3 then it's just a matter of using the process of elimination. Does your server support 32 or 64GB of RAM? If it supports 32GB then it's Gen 1, if it supports 64GB then it's Gen 2. If they were purchased in 2006 then my guess is they're Gen 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Visual Indicator on the Chasis

If you don't have a circle with a `II` or `III` then it's a `I`:

[image]

credit - [Dell community forum](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19457437)

Answer (score 4):

It's by age. So I use the HP equivalent, the DL360/380 G5. The servers were introduced in 2006 and followed the Intel XXXXX product line. The first CPUs to be supported were the dual-core Intel 5100-series. These were followed by the quad-core Intel 5300-series, and later, the quad-core Intel 5400-series.

That explains the Gen1, Gen2 and Gen3... They all used Intel 5000X chipsets and similar components.

If your server is from 2006, it's the first generation.

Answer (score 2):

on the front left side of the face plate you will see a II or a III for gen 2 and gen 3. If there are no  roman numerals then it is a gen I